# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, imagemagick, image-uploading

I have an application that when running locally spits out the following error when trying to upload a profile picture. I have ImageMagick installed. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall but that did not solve the problem. Anything I should have an eye out for in routes.rb? Having issues where to look next...If there is a better method to handle profile pictures, recommendations are welcome.:

```
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users"):
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

routes.rb (where references users):

```
 namespace :api do
namespace :v1 do

  resources :users, only: [:create, :update, :delete, :show]
  post 'users/login', to: 'users#login', as: :login

  get 'users/:user_id/place/:requesting_user_id', to: 'userfeed#show'
  get 'users/:user_id/feed', to: 'feed#show' # all my friends feed

  post 'users/:user_id/follow', to: 'friend#follow'
  post 'users/:user_id/unfollow', to: 'friend#unfollow'
```

...

Comment: Post the contents of your `routes.rb`

Comment: Most of the time this is related with something in 'routes.rb' and and not related to I guess Paperclip in your case. Post more information. At least your routes. So help is possible

Comment: I have posted the routes.rb that references users

Answer (score 2):

You configured your routes for `users` to only include `:create`, `:update`, `:delete`, `:show`. If you add `:index`, the error should go away.

`resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :update, :delete, :show]`

Of course, that means you'll need an index action on the controller.

For example in users_controller.rb you might add:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

However, I suspect you could configure the method you use to save the image to redirect to a user profile view instead of a user listing view to avoid adding this new action.

Comment: would I put that in the users_controller.rb? And what would that look like?

Comment: Yup, it would go in the users controller. The index method typically assigns all users to a variable so they can be displayed in the view.